# Can resize but cannot reorder toolbars on taskbar in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, toolbar

The taskbar is not locked. I can change the height of the taskbar.

I can drag the toolbar handle to resize the toolbar width but if I click/hold/drag [cursor has 4 direction arrows] then it will not allow the reordering of the toolbars